# Bean references are not creating when using quartz with spring scheduler - Job instantiation failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, quartz-scheduler, spring-boot-2

I have updated my spring-boot application from 1.x to 2.x after upgrade scheduler is not working as expected. Getting the following exception.

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:47)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:392) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.schedulers.simplejobs.SimpleJobExecutions': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sampleService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.service.SampleService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:351)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory.createJobInstance(SpringBeanJobFactory.java:90)
        at com.scheduler.factory.JobFactory.createJobInstance(JobFactory.java:35)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:43)
        ... 2 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.service.SampleService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1655)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
```

I have tried many references from SO and suggested configurations didn't help.

Below are the stack details.

Spring boot 2.1.5

Spring 5.1.7

Quartz 2.3.1

Here is my codebase.

```java
public final class JobFactory  extends SpringBeanJobFactory {

    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobFactory.class);

    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
        Stream.of(context.getBeanDefinitionNames())
            .filter(s -> s.startsWith("sample"))
            .forEach(beanName -> LOGGER.debug("applicationContext beans {}",beanName));
        beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        LOGGER.debug("createJobInstance job {}",job);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        LOGGER.debug("createJobInstance autowireBean job {}",job);
        return job;
    }
```

```java
@Component
public class SimpleJobExecutions extends QuartzJobBean {


    @Autowired
    public SampleService sampleService;

    @Override
    public void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)  throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            SampleDTO sample = new SampleDTO();
            sample.setName("Name");
            sample.setAge(25);
            SampleDTO sampleObj = sampleService.save(sample);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new JobExecutionException(ex);
        }
    }
```

```java
@Service("sampleService")
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {

    @Autowired
    SampleRepository sampleRepository;

    @Autowired
    SampleMapper sampleMapper;

   @Override
   public SampleDTO save(SampleDTO sampleDTO) {
      log.info("Request to save Sample : {}", sampleDTO);
      Sample sample = sampleMapper.toEntity(sampleDTO);
      sample = sampleRepository.save(sample);
      return sampleMapper.toDto(sample);
  }

}
```

I can able to print all the beans from application context but it's not injecting at the time of job execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the root cause of this problem.

Autowiring other bean references are started working after removing the following dependencies.

```xml
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

dev tools dependencies are creating conflicts with application dependencies and it's not allowing to create the bean references only in QuartzJobBean executions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I will try to answer the question

By default your **SchedulerFactoryBean** uses AdaptableJobFactory( https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html#setJobFactory-org.quartz.spi.JobFactory) which does not have the autowiring capabalities so you need to Specify an instance of Spring's SpringBeanJobFactory here basically
you need to specify it to the scheduler.
ex:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    JobFactory jobFactory = new JobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    schedulerFactoryBean.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    return schedulerFactoryBean;
}
```

**Alternative approach :**

if the above code is not working you then you can simply try to get the bean from the application context inside your executeInternal() method

```
 @Component
public class SimpleJobExecutions extends QuartzJobBean {

    @Override
    public void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)  throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            ApplicationContext applicationContext = (ApplicationContext)
                        context.getScheduler().getContext().get("applicationContext");
            SampleService sampleService = (SampleService) applicationContext.getBean(SampleService.class);
            SampleDTO sample = new SampleDTO();
            sample.setName("Name");
            sample.setAge(25);
            SampleDTO sampleObj = sampleService.save(sample);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new JobExecutionException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, regarding the line `@Autowired public SampleServiceImpl sampleService;` in `SimpleJobExecutions` class, it would be a good practice to code to interfaces.

I feel that  there is a proxy bean in container which implements `SimpleService` and since your are trying to inject `SimpleServiceImpl` it is not injected.(note that the proxy Object is not 'SimpleServiceImp').

To test if this is your case just try to inject `SimpleServiceImpl` by interface.

Simply replace:

```
@Autowired public SampleServiceImpl sampleService;
```

with

```
@Autowired public SampleService sampleService;
```

hope it helps.

Update: (just make some clarification)

When your bean is wrapped by a proxy, the proxy object implements the interface of your bean and since in previous version of your question (before edit) you were injecting a bean by class (instead of interface), there was no bean of such class (but there was one with the interface type), therefore container was unable to find such a bean and it threw:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:  No qualifying bean of type 'com.service.SampleService' available
```